# Form/Serial/Merge letter - output to separate PDF files

Tags: letters

I am currently setting up a serial letter (ie. one letter/same content, multiple recipients). My current script outputs all pages in one, long PDF document. Is there way to make LaTeX generate separate PDFs, one for each letter?

Main TeX document:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt]{g-brief}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}

\usepackage{graphicx,type1cm,eso-pic,color}

\lochermarke
\faltmarken
%\fenstermarken
\trennlinien


\Name                {My Name}
\Strasse             {My Street 123}
\Zusatz              {}
\RetourAdresse       {}
\Ort                 {12345 Whereilive}
\Land                {}

\Telefon             {555-1212}
\Telefax             {555-1313}
\EMail               {some@address.com}

\Unterschrift        {My Name}

\Adresse             {
Some \\ Recipient\\Address}

\Betreff             {Why am I writing to You today?}

\Datum               {\today}
%\IhrZeichen          {} 
%\IhrSchreiben        {}
%\MeinZeichen         {cts 20100506.1}

\Anrede              {Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\Gruss               {Mit freundlichem Gruss,}{1cm}

\Anlagen             {\emph{Anlage: some other page}}

\newcommand{\BriefAn}[5]
{
  \newpage
  \Adresse{#1 #2\\ #3 \\\\ \textbf{#4}}


  \begin{g-brief}

\shorthandoff{"}

I would like to ask you this
\begin{enumerate}
\item yabber yabber
\item somme foobar
\item more yabber
\item more foobar
\item enough of this already
\end{enumerate}



  \end{g-brief}
}

\begin{document}
\input{Adressen.tex}
\end{document}

\endinput
```

Adressen.tex contains this:

```
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
```

Comment: A single run of `pdflatex` can produce only one PDF file.

Comment: But a Single Run of 'pdflatex' may call other instances of itself, so there might be a way. However using pdftk might be easier

Comment: What about calling `pdftk` from `pdflatex`? (LaTeX is where we can easily get the info about partitioning into pages.)

Answer (score 4):

You can exploit the `write18` facility and invoke `pdftk` ([link for pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)) from within latex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
%% ----------------- Your addresses here--------------------------
\begin{filecontents*}{Adressen.tex}
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
\BriefAn{Firstname}{Lastname}{Some Street 314}{12345 Somewhere}{m}
\end{filecontents*}
% ------------------main letter -- letters.tex here--------------------------------
\begin{filecontents*}{letters.tex}
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt]{g-brief}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}

\usepackage{graphicx,type1cm,eso-pic,color}

\lochermarke
\faltmarken
%\fenstermarken
\trennlinien


\Name                {My Name}
\Strasse             {My Street 123}
\Zusatz              {}
\RetourAdresse       {}
\Ort                 {12345 Whereilive}
\Land                {}

\Telefon             {555-1212}
\Telefax             {555-1313}
\EMail               {some@address.com}

\Unterschrift        {My Name}

\Adresse             {
Some \\ Recipient\\Address}

\Betreff             {Why am I writing to You today?}

\Datum               {\today}
%\IhrZeichen          {} 
%\IhrSchreiben        {}
%\MeinZeichen         {cts 20100506.1}

\Anrede              {Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\Gruss               {Mit freundlichem Gruss,}{1cm}

\Anlagen             {\emph{Anlage: some other page}}

\newcommand{\BriefAn}[5]
{
  \newpage
  \Adresse{#1 #2\\ #3 \\\\ \textbf{#4}}


  \begin{g-brief}

\shorthandoff{"}

I would like to ask you this
\begin{enumerate}
\item yabber yabber
\item somme foobar
\item more yabber
\item more foobar
\item enough of this already
\end{enumerate}    
  \end{g-brief}
}

\begin{document}
\input{Adressen.tex}
\end{document}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
% Compile your document
\immediate\write18{pdflatex letters}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
% Split in to individual pages
%\immediate\write18{pdftk letters.pdf burst allow Printing}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{pdftk letters.pdf burst allow Printing output letter-page-\@percentchar02d.pdf}
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------------------------    
\begin{document}
  Check for the individual pages in different files with names \verb|letter-page-<page number>| in the same folder as this \verb|.tex| file.
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `pdflatex`. You will get 4 pdf files with names `letter-page-<page number>` in the same folder.

Comment: Speldid idea - doesn't work for me, though :( I get this in my logfile: `runsystem(pdflatex letters)...disabled (restricted).

runsystem(pdftk letters.pdf burst allow Printing output letter-page-%02d.pdf)..
.disabled (restricted).` `pdftk` is installed and working.